# Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This error is beginning to drive me nuts, so I thought I would ask here now.

Bootstrap.js keeps saying that it requires jQuery, even tho I have defined jQuery in the header and bootstrap.js is loaded in the footer, as you can see in the source.

What could the reason be for this..?

Site: fliva.com

This is a Wordpress website.

UPDATE

The jQuery version used is: 2.2.4 which is located in the head of the dom, if you look in the source it should be clear. Bootstrap.js is loaded further down in the bottom.

This is a real mystery to me..

Comment: Which version of jQuery have you included in the head. You need to include jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3.3.6 JQuery 2.2.4 Version Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584520/bootstrap-3-3-6-jquery-2-2-4-version-exception)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584520/bootstrap-3-3-6-jquery-2-2-4-version-exception Please have a look at this question. This is the same problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have multiple versions of `jQuery` included causing a conflict.

The error I see is

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher
```

Although `$.fn.jquery` returns `2.2.4`

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I've looked through the document several times now, without seeing a second jQuery reference.

Comment: Either your theme or one of your plugins is including an older jquery version. You have to disable/enable to find out. I suspect it to be your theme.