# Bower in VS2015.3 download wrong version

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, bower

i´m having problems with bower inside VS on an aspnet core 1.0 project. My bower.json is this

```js
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.4",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6"
  }
}
```

But when I go to the libs that bower downloaded i find that jquery is v3.1.0

```js
/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v3.1.0
 * https://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * https://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2016-07-07T21:44Z
 */
```

I thought it was my machine but it happened to me in three different machines. am i doing something wrong??

**Edit:**
I tried with this:

```js
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.2.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery":  "<=2.2.4"
  }
}
```

The only package configured in bower.json is jquery and still installs jquery 3.0.1. Why is bower doing that? The Output window for npm/bower says:

> PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\Bower.cmd" install --force-latest
>
> bower jquery#~2.2.4             cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.4
>
> bower jquery#~2.2.4           validate 2.2.4 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#~2.2.4
>
> bower jquery          extra-resolution Unnecessary resolution: jquery#<=2.2.4
>
> bower jquery#~2.2.4            install jquery#2.2.4
>
> jquery#2.2.4 wwwroot\bower\jquery

Comment: Are you looking in the correct folder? Bower might be installing to a different folder than you might think...

Comment: Yes, i´m looking at the  right folder. I've configured a different folder. I also tried with the default project and it has the same behaviour

Comment: Oh, I just saw something... `--force-latest` is appended to your bower command, so, it's doing exactly that. There's probably a setting for that somewhere in visual studio. I don't have it in front of me, but I'd look for bower settings in Tools>Options... probably under Web, then something about packages.

Comment: There are no settings for bower in VS. How could this be solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue in the tooling repo:

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/575

I simply switched to npm, which resolves the correct package version just fine.

Comment: Agree, the only solution I found was to switch to npm. I liked it more.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue and have successfully resolved it. There is a problem with bower that was shipped with Visual Studio 2015, possibly introduced in one of the Visual Studio updates. What you can do:

1. install Git (dependency)
2. install nodejs
3. install bower
4. Configure Visual Studio options to use your installed version of nodejs
5. Delete bower cache folder %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\bower

reference:
http://josharepoint.com/2016/05/04/how-to-configure-visual-studio-2015-integration-with-latest-version-of-node-js-and-npm/

Answer (score 2):

Another **temporal** hack, until Microsoft fix the problem could be change contents of `bower.cmd` to remove the `--force-latest` string from parameters list.

The file `bower.cmd` on my Visual Studio 2015.3 installation is located on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External`.

You should replace:

```
@"%~dp0\node" "%~dp0\node_modules\bower\bin\bower" %*
```

With:

```
ECHO OFF
set params=%*
ECHO %params% | %WINDIR%\system32\FIND "--force-latest" >nul & 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (call set params=%%params:--force-latest=%%%)
@"%~dp0\node" "%~dp0\node_modules\bower\bin\bower" %params%
```

The above piece of code will check parameters and, if `--force-latest` exists, will be removed and then execute bower with clear parameters string.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The script removes the --force-latest parameter perfectly, but Bower still just gets jQuery 3.1.1 (even though it thinks it downloaded 2.2.3)

Comment: @Jobbo check the into the hidden file "bower.json" (in your project root) the "resolutions" section, probably is referencing jQuery 3.1.1 as version to solve conflicts... ( by old wrong parameter )

Comment: After applying the fix to the .cmd file I also tried editing bower.json manually. I completely removed the 'resolutions' section and set the only 'dependency' as "jquery":"2.2.3", but Bower still gets 3.1.1. The description of --force-latest is 'Force latest version on conflict' so I'm not convinced removing it makes a difference in this case

Comment: @Jobbo, exactly, --force-latest is "Force latest version on conflic", I was getting 3.1.1 by a conflict with Bootstrap... After patch it worked by me, check: https://postimg.org/image/h4urheaed/

Comment: My bower.cmd is exactly as you've posted. I opened a new solution and uninstalled all existing packages, then added Bootstrap 3.3.6 and jQuery 2.2.4. Bower then downloaded Bootstrap 4 alpha, and jQuery 3.1.1. What could I be doing wrong?: https://postimg.org/image/5q4hgggsd/

Comment: This fixed the issue (with the default bower.cmd from VS): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584520/bootstrap-3-3-6-jquery-2-2-4-version-exception/38460014#38460014

Comment: This plus clearing bower cache as suggested by @cronixis solved it for me with VS2015 Update 3 and the preview 2 of the ASP.NET Core MVC Tooling for VS2015. I think there is chance that different combinations of versions may require a different fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it be removing jquery package, add then add it manually to bower.json with right version:
"jquery": "2.2.4",
Hope this will help someone.

Comment: It did not work for me. I've tried it manually, with the ui, but bower always installs the latest version. Also it happens for all the packages. Although i specify the version on any package, bower installs the latest.

Answer (score 0):

This is a GIT wrapper problem, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584520/bootstrap-3-3-6-jquery-2-2-4-version-exception/38460014#38460014) was very helpful resolving this issue:
Installed [GIT for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and changed Visual Studio External Web Tools
(Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->External Web Tools) from "$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External\git" to "C:\program files\git\bin"
cleared the temp files and restored bower.

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

My, somewhat hackish, solution was to remove the explicit version of jQuery from bower.json and have bootstrap itself resolve that dependency.

My bower.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0"
  }
}
```