# Bower .NET core bootstrap not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gulp, asp.net-core, bower

I have started a project in .NET Core and have used bower to install bootstrap for me. I'm having issues getting the bootstrap navigation styling to work. If I install bootstrap through bower, does it not come with everything from bootstrap? My button styling appears to be working. If I use the CDN, the styling appears for the navigation menu, so I know I'm using the right classes.

Here is what I have for the navigation menu.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><button role="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and here is my project structure.

[image: Project structure]

One of my potential issues may be that I'm using gulp as well. Here is my gulp tasks that handle scripts and styles.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');

gulp.task('js', function () {
    // scripts
    gulp.src([
        './wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        './wwwroot/lib/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js',
        './wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'])
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib/Site'));

});

gulp.task('css', function () {
    // bootstrap 
    gulp.src([
        './wwwroot/lib/tether/dist/css/tether.min.css',
        './wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-flex.min.css',
        './wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css',
        './wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css',
        './wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'])

    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib/Site'));

});
```

and referencing in my head of the _Layout.cshtml, I have a reference to it as shown.

```
<environment names="Development">
        @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />*@        
        <link href="~/lib/Site/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </environment>
```

I want some understanding of either why not everything is included for bootstrap with bower, or what I am doing wrong in my gulpfile.

Comment: I suggest look to see what version of bootstrap it pulled down, there is an issue affecting some people where it is pulling down bootstrap 4 even though they asked for 3.x https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/665

Comment: @JoeAudette how do I make sure it has the right version? When I open bootstrap.css, it says "Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.5". So I think it is doing what you're suggesting. What's an alternative way to pull down the correct one?

Comment: @JoeAudette thank you, you were right. The wrong version was installed. I followed the directions from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584520/bootstrap-3-3-6-jquery-2-2-4-version-exception/38460014#38460014 and found an answer from the github issues you had linked.