# Visual Studio 2015 .NET Core Bower Permission Error when Installing Packages

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, bower

I created a .NET Core Application in Visual Studio 2015, and this project includes Bower as a Package Manager.  Here is the Manage Bower Packages Interface:

[image]

When using the Manage Bower Packages Interface I have tried to install or update anything, and I am consistently getting a permission error like this:

ECMDERR Failed to execute "git clone https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git -b 1.11.3 --progress . --depth 1", exit code of #128 fatal: Could not switch to '.': Permission denied

1st Modification I have tried to change the json bower configuration file .bowerrc from this:

```
{
    "directory": "www/lib"
}
```

to look like this:

```
{
    "directory": "www/lib",
    "allow_root": true
}
```

2nd Modification I Configured Git to use http instead of git:// with Git Bash

```
git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://
```

Also Configured VS 2015 to use the new installed Git over VS Git

```
Right clicked on Bower folder under Dependencies, then selected Configure external tools; 
Unchecked "$(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git"
Added a new node with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
```

3rd Modification to Edit the file bower.cmd
[Previous Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725727/vs-2015-bower-does-not-work-behind-firewall/31538406#31538406) indicated bower.cmd was located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External
```

This Path doesn't exist in my setup, however it exists here where I modified bower.cmd:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External
```

I modified bower.cmd similar to [Previous Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725727/vs-2015-bower-does-not-work-behind-firewall/31538406#31538406):

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\;%PATH%
@"%~dp0\node\node" "%~dp0\bower\node_modules\bower\bin\bower" %*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved $(PATH) above $(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External

Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, External Web Tools

[image]

I modified the installed Jquery to previous version 1.11.3 
Bower Console Manager indicates that 2.2.3 is installed, however, 
bower.json indicates 1.11.3 is installed.  Also I tried installing boostrap 3.3.7 which does not provide option, it only has option for bootstrap 3.3.6.
I believe this problem is part of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584520/bootstrap-3-3-6-jquery-2-2-4-version-exception/38460014#38460014)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm` is a Linux command. It is not helpful if you are developping on Windows.

Try to add `bower.json` file to your project in Visual Studio and write the code:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Save the file. I have never used Manage Bower Packages Interface but editing `bower.json` always worked. It should create the files under `wwwroot/lib/jquery/`.

Comment: I already have bower.json and there I had also tried to modify the jquery from 2.2.0 to 1.11.3 but I get the same error

Comment: So it is a permission problem. Open a command prompt in a random folder of your Documents and run the command `git clone https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git -b 1.11.3 --progress . --depth 1`. Do you get the same permission error? If you get an error like 'git' is not recognized, retype the command but start it with the full path to your git executable like `C:\Programs\Git\git.exe clone ...`

Comment: Within Visual Studio 2015/Projects Folder I ran the command without --depth 1,, this created jquery-dist folder within that same /Projects Folder,, however I'm still receiving same error from within VS from other project within /Projects

Comment: I remember now that, in Visual Studio 2015, I am mainly using tools (such as Git, NPM) that I installed as a standalone, and ask Visual Studio to choose them in priority. Follow the step 1 and 3 in the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725727/vs-2015-bower-does-not-work-behind-firewall/31538406#31538406 If it works for you, I will edit my answer to point this link. There is some chances it can fix your problem.

Comment: I went with the first solution,, Item 3 was slightly different in my VS whereby I unchecked $(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External\git  and added C:\Program Files\Git\bin    but I'm still getting that error